# главный класс проекта в Java

Tags: java, jvm

Здравствуйте скажите, пожалуйста, что такое главный класс программы? Например, есть класс1 - родитель, класс2 - наследник и класс 3 -отдельный класс . Какой из них будет главным или главным будет другой класс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Главным классом программы называют класс, в котором лежит функция

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  ...
}
```

Вы наверное имели ввиду суперкласс, это класс Object для любых объектов  по умолчанию, в вашей ситуации для класс1 - Object, для класс2 - класс1, для класс3 - Object

Comment: спасибо все очень понятно)